# How to set time to 00 format in xdsoft's datetimepicker?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, datetimepicker

I am Using https://xdsoft.net/jqplugins/datetimepicker/ for date and time picker but there is an issue in their site that time picker time is not taking `00:00` format but its taking every time on refresh randomly like `00:31` etc, as seen as  below image.

This issue is also happing on reference site also.

Is there any solution to take time in `00:00` format like 01:00, 02:00, 03:00, and so on ?

**Html Code**

```
<input id="datetimepicker" type="text" >
```

**javaScript**

```
jQuery('#datetimepicker').datetimepicker({
  datepicker:false,
  format:'H:i'
});
```

[image]

Comment: Why is this tagged with `html` and `css`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try below solution for that.

```
jQuery('#datetimepicker').datetimepicker({
  datepicker:false,
  format:'H:i',
  allowTimes:[
    '00:00', '01:00', '02:00', '03:00', '04:00', '05:00', '06:00', '07:00','08:00', '09:00', '10:00', '11:00', '12:00', '13:00', '14:00', '15:00', 
    '16:00','17:00', '18:00', '19:00', '20:00', '21:00', '22:00', '23:00'
    ],
});
```

Hope this is work for you.